# Removing nodes from a Doubly linked list correctly

Tags: c

While trying to remove nodes, I'm able to free the memory allocated, but unable to assign it to NULL so my program stops printing these addresses. I'm led to believe that I MUST use double pointers to do this.

I've tried equaling to NULL after freeing, but that crashes the program.

```
typedef struct Linked_List_type
{
    struct Node_type *first;
    struct Node_type *last;
} LinkedList;
typedef struct Node_type
{
    int data;
    char name[15];
    char phone[15];
    struct Node_type *next;
    struct Node_type *prev;
} Node;
//This is how I insert
void LinkedList_insert (LinkedList * this, int val, char * name, char * phone)
{
//creo un nodo para insertar
    Node *it = this->first;
    Node *newNode = new_Node (val, name, phone);
    if (!this)
    {
        printf ("Lista no creada\n");
    }
    for (it = this->first; it != NULL; it = it->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(it->name, name)==0) //Evitar repeticiC3n
        {
            printf ("Valor repetido\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!this->first)
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        this->last = newNode;
        this->first = newNode;
//first y last ocupan el mismo valor, siguiente apunta a nulo
//solo si la lista estC! vacC-a
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->prev = this->last;
        this->last->next = newNode;
        this->last = this->last->next;
    }
}
//This is how I remove 
Bool LinkedList_removestr(LinkedList * this, char * str)
{
    Node * tmp = NULL;
    Node * it = this->first;
    Bool Bandera = FALSE;
    while(it!=NULL)
    {
        if(it->next!=NULL && strcmp(it->name,str)==0)
        {
            tmp=it;
            it=it->next;
            free(tmp);
            Bandera=TRUE;
        }
        if(it->next==NULL && strcmp(it->name,str)==0)//si first es igual al que quiero remover
        {
            tmp=it;
            free(tmp);//no apunto a next porque no hay
            Bandera=TRUE;
        }
        it=it->next;
    }
    return Bandera;
}
```

After removal, when printing the list, I expect the list to skip the removed node address, or not show it, but after using my remove function, when printing the list, the Node prints the address, I belive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a node `it`, you need to both replace the previous node's next pointer with `it->next`, and replace the next node's previous pointer with `it->prev`.

However, when doing this you must also account for the special cases at the start and end of the list:

```
if (it->prev != NULL)
    it->prev->next = it->next;
else
    this->first = it->next;

if (it->next != NULL)
    it->next->prev = it->prev;
else
    this->last = it->prev;
```

Your `tmp` variable should just be used to save the pointer to the next node to be examined, in case `it` is freed.  Putting it all into your loop:

```
Bool LinkedList_removestr(LinkedList * this, char * str)
{
    Node * tmp = NULL;
    Node * it = this->first;
    Bool Bandera = FALSE;

    while (it != NULL)
    {
        /* Save it->next, because 'it' may be freed */
        tmp = it->next;

        if (strcmp(it->name, str) == 0)
        {
            Bandera = TRUE;

            /* Adjust next pointer of previous node */
            if (it->prev != NULL)
                it->prev->next = it->next;
            else
                this->first = it->next;

            /* Adjust previous pointer of next node */
            if (it->next != NULL)
                it->next->prev = it->prev;
            else
                this->last = it->prev;

            free(it);
        }

        it = tmp;
    }

    return Bandera;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! You're right about this. However, what if I'm about to remove the first/last (only) Node? would tmp=it->next cause a crash? since it->next would be NULL, even though at the end you put it = tmp which I believe would keep the program from entering into an infinite loop, it still crashes my program, or would this be an error somewhere else? Thank you in advance! Great explanation.

Comment: `tmp = it->next;` is fine if `it->next == NULL` - it's equivalent to just `tmp = NULL;`.  It's only if `it == NULL` that it would be a problem, but we know that is *not* the case because the loop would have exited if `it` was `NULL`.